# How to tether a Linux PC to a Windows PC?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, tethering

I am in the process of changing Internet providers and currently have no Internet at home. On weekdays, I can manage with using Internet only on the smartphone, but for the weekends, I'd like to have Internet on my desktop PC, which runs Ubuntu Maverick.

I have a 3G modem which uses a prepaid tarif, so I can pay for Internet use for a day when I need it. But it only works when the software for managing connections and balance is installed. So I have to use it on the Windows 7 laptop, I can't connect it to the Ubuntu desktop.

I usually don't connect the two PCs in a network. But if I do, is there a way to tether them (using an Ethernet cable - I must have a crossed one laying around, or through the old wireless router I used with the last provider) so the Ubuntu PC can access the Internet?

I'm not experienced with networks, so if you can point me to a good guide in addition to hinting at the steps needed, it would be great. I tried to google one, but all results are about tethering to phones.

Comment: FYI, modern network cards don't care whether you use a normal or crossover cable.

Answer (score 2):

This is incomplete, but should give you more info to search on: It depends on the version of Windows you have. In some of the versions you can use 'internet connection sharing' on the Windows machine, and then connect the Linux machine to the Windows machine using a network cable. Connect your Windows machine to the Internet via the phone as usual. Share that connection from the network control panel. I believe Windows will then start up a DHCP server, giving your Linux machine all the network config details it requires to use the Internet through the Windows machine.